# deleting duplicates in 2d array python

Tags: python, twitter, duplicates

I am trying to delete duplicates in a dictionary but only based on duplicates in the text values

so for example I want to delete the duplicates this list of tweets:

```
{'text': 'Dear Conservatives: comprehend, if you can RT Iran deal opponents have their "death panels" lie, and it\'s a whopper http://example.com/EcSHCAm9Nn', 'id': 634092907243393024L}
{'text': 'RT Iran deal opponents now have their "death panels" lie, and it\'s a whopper http://example.com/ntECOXorvK via @voxdotcom #IranDeal', 'id': 634068454207791104L}
{'text': 'RT : Iran deal quietly picks up some GOP backers via https://example.com/65DRjWT6t8 catoletters: Iran deal quietly picks up some GOP backers \xe2\x80\xa6', 'id': 633631425279991812L}
{'text': 'RT : Iran deal quietly picks up some GOP backers via https://example.com/QD43vbJft6 catoletters: Iran deal quietly picks up some GOP backers \xe2\x80\xa6', 'id': 633495091584323584L}
{'text': "RT : Iran Deal's Surprising Supporters: https://example.com/pUG7vht0fE catoletters: Iran Deal's Surprising Supporters: http://example.com/dhdylTNgoG", 'id': 633083989180448768L}
{'text': "RT : Iran Deal's Surprising Supporters - Today on the Liberty Report: https://example.com/PVHuVTyuAG RonPaul: Iran Deal'\xe2\x80\xa6 https://example.com/sTBhL12llF", 'id': 632525323733729280L}
{'text': "RT : Iran Deal's Surprising Supporters - Today on the Liberty Report: https://example.com/PVHuVTyuAG RonPaul: Iran Deal'\xe2\x80\xa6 https://example.com/sTBhL12llF", 'id': 632385798277595137L}
{'text': "RT : Iran Deal's Surprising Supporters: https://example.com/hOUCmreHKA catoletters: Iran Deal's Surprising Supporters: http://example.com/bJSLhd9dqA", 'id': 632370745088323584L}
{'text': '#News #RT Iran deal debate devolves into clash over Jewish stereotypes and survival - W... http://example.com/foU0Sz6Jej http://example.com/WvcaNkMcu3', 'id': 631952088981868544L}
{'text': '"@JeffersonObama: RT Iran deal support from Democratic senators is 19-1 so far....but...but Schumer...."', 'id': 631951056189149184L}}
```

to get this:

```
{'text': 'Dear Conservatives: comprehend, if you can RT Iran deal opponents have their "death panels" lie, and it\'s a whopper http://example.com/EcSHCAm9Nn', 'id': 634092907243393024L}
{'text': '"@JeffersonObama: RT Iran deal support from Democratic senators is 19-1 so far....but...but Schumer...."', 'id': 631951056189149184L}}
```

so far I've mostly found answer based on 'normal' dictionaries where the duplicate key/value are identical . In my case it's a merged dictionary. The text keys are identical due to retweets but the corresponding tweet id's are different

This is the entire code, any tips on writing the tweets in a csv file in a more efficient way (making the deletion of duplicates easier) are mor than welcome.

```
import csv
import codecs
tweet_text_id = []

from TwitterSearch import TwitterSearchOrder, TwitterUserOrder,    TwitterSearchException, TwitterSearch
try:
tso = TwitterSearchOrder() 
tso.set_keywords(["Iran Deal"]) 
tso.set_language('en')
tso.set_include_entities(False) 



ts = TwitterSearch(
    consumer_key = "aaaaa",
    consumer_secret = "bbbbb",
    access_token = "cccc",
    access_token_secret = "dddd"
 )

for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
    tweet_text_id.append({'id':tweet['id'], 'text': tweet['text'].encode('utf8')});



fieldnames = ['id', 'text']
tweet_file = open('tweets.csv', 'wb')
csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(tweet_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
csvwriter.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in fieldnames))
for row in tweet_text_id:
    csvwriter.writerow(row)
tweet_file.close()

except TwitterSearchException as e: 
     print(e)
```

Comment: What you have is a list of dictionaries, not a "merged dictionary". In any case, your example isn't clear. You want to keep only the first and last entries, but the others aren't all exact duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I made a module that filters out repeat instances and removes hashtags on the way"

```
__all__ = ['filterDuplicates']
import re

hashRegex = re.compile(r'#[a-z0-9]+', re.IGNORECASE)
trunOne = re.compile(r'^\s+')
trunTwo = re.compile(r'\s+$')

def filterDuplicates(tweets):

    dupes = []
    new_dict = []

    for dic in tweets:
        new_txt = hashRegex.sub('', dic['text']) #Removes hashtags
        new_txt = trunOne.sub('', trunTwo.sub('', new_txt)) #Truncates extra spaces

        print(new_txt)

        dic.update({'text':new_txt})

        if new_txt in dupes:
            continue

        dupes.append(new_txt)
        new_dict.append(dic)

    return new_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':

    the_tweets = [
        {'text':'#yolo #swag something really annoying', 'id':1},
        {'text':'something really annoying', 'id':2},
        {'text':'thing thing thing haha', 'id':3},
        {'text':'#RF thing thing thing haha', 'id':4},
        {'text':'thing thing thing haha', 'id':5}
    ]

    #Tweets pre-filter
    for dic in the_tweets:
        print(dic)

    #Tweets post-filter
    for dic in filterDuplicates(the_tweets):
        print(dic)
```

Just import this in your script and run it to filter out the tweets!

Answer (score 0):

You could try comparing tweets based on the "edit distance" between them.  Here's my crack at it using fuzzywuzzy[1] to compare the tweets:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


def clean_tweet(tweet):
    """very crude.  You can improve on this!"""
    tweet['text'] = tweet['text'].replace("RT :", "")
    return tweet


def is_unique(tweet, seen_tweets):
    for seen_tweet in seen_tweets:
        ratio = fuzz.ratio(tweet['text'], seen_tweet['text'])
        if ratio > DUP_THRESHOLD:
            return False
    return True


def dedup(tweets, threshold=50):
    deduped = []
    for tweet in tweets:
        cleaned = clean_tweet(tweet)
        if is_unique(cleaned, deduped):
            deduped.append(cleaned)

    return deduped


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DUP_THRESHOLD = 30

    tweets = [
        {'text': 'Dear Conservatives: comprehend, if you can RT Iran deal opponents have their "death panels" lie, and it\'s a whopper http://t.co/EcSHCAm9Nn', 'id': 634092907243393024},
        {'text': 'RT Iran deal opponents now have their "death panels" lie, and it\'s a whopper http://t.co/ntECOXorvK via @voxdotcom #IranDeal', 'id': 634068454207791104},
        {'text': 'RT : Iran deal quietly picks up some GOP backers via https://t.co/65DRjWT6t8 catoletters: Iran deal quietly picks up some GOP backers \xe2\x80\xa6', 'id': 633631425279991812},
        {'text': 'RT : Iran deal quietly picks up some GOP backers via https://t.co/QD43vbJft6 catoletters: Iran deal quietly picks up some GOP backers \xe2\x80\xa6', 'id': 633495091584323584},
        {'text': "RT : Iran Deal's Surprising Supporters: https://t.co/pUG7vht0fE catoletters: Iran Deal's Surprising Supporters: http://t.co/dhdylTNgoG", 'id': 633083989180448768},
        {'text': "RT : Iran Deal's Surprising Supporters - Today on the Liberty Report: https://t.co/PVHuVTyuAG RonPaul: Iran Deal'\xe2\x80\xa6 https://t.co/sTBhL12llF", 'id': 632525323733729280},
        {'text': "RT : Iran Deal's Surprising Supporters - Today on the Liberty Report: https://t.co/PVHuVTyuAG RonPaul: Iran Deal'\xe2\x80\xa6 https://t.co/sTBhL12llF", 'id': 632385798277595137},
        {'text': "RT : Iran Deal's Surprising Supporters: https://t.co/hOUCmreHKA catoletters: Iran Deal's Surprising Supporters: http://t.co/bJSLhd9dqA", 'id': 632370745088323584},
        {'text': '#News #RT Iran deal debate devolves into clash over Jewish stereotypes and survival - W... http://t.co/foU0Sz6Jej http://t.co/WvcaNkMcu3', 'id': 631952088981868544},
        {'text': '"@JeffersonObama: RT Iran deal support from Democratic senators is 19-1 so far....but...but Schumer...."', 'id': 631951056189149184},
    ]

    deduped = dedup(tweets, threshold=DUP_THRESHOLD)
    print deduped
```

which gives the output:

```
[
    {'text': 'Dear Conservatives: comprehend, if you can RT Iran deal opponents have their "death panels" lie, and it\'s a whopper http://t.co/EcSHCAm9Nn', 'id': 634092907243393024L},
    {'text': ' Iran deal quietly picks up some GOP backers via https://t.co/65DRjWT6t8 catoletters: Iran deal quietly picks up some GOP backers \xe2\x80\xa6', 'id': 633631425279991812L}
]
```

[1] https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy